# Wordpress configuration via add_filter

Tags: wordpress

I just read up on Wordpress' automatic updater.  Wanting to disable it I searched and found [a page describing how to configure Wordpress auto update](http://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates#Configuration_via_Filters).  At first I tried using the filter method, but after putting the line

```
add_filter( 'automatic_updater_disabled', '__return_true' );
```

in my `wp-config.php` the site was completely broken.  I had to revert to using

```
define( 'AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true );
```

which in my case is just as good.  But say that I want to do more fine grained configuration, which requires me to use filters, how do I make that work, where do I put the configuration if not in `wp-config.php`?

Comment: This would probably be better moved to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you make sure you copied it in after `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');` in the wp-config.php file? For example:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);


/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');

add_filter( 'automatic_updater_disabled', '__return_true' );
```

You need to do this so WordPress loads first, then it can use the add_filter() function. Not sure if that is the best method. I would try and use it in custom plugin or in a pinch use functions.php.

Comment: That solved it indeed.  There's no mention in the WP instructions about exactly where to place lines.

Comment: Some people consider adding stuff after `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');` [a bad practice](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/1310#issuecomment-53268344).

Answer (score 2):

According to the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Disabling_Automatic_Background_Updates#Configuration_via_Filters):

> The best place to put these filters is in a must-use plugin.
>
> Note: Do not add add_filter() calls in wp-config.php - causes conflicts with WP-CLI and possibly other problems.

What is a [must-use plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins).?

> Must-use plugins (a.k.a. mu-plugins) are plugins installed in a special directory inside the content folder and which are automatically enabled on all sites in the installation. Must-use plugins do not show in the default list of plugins on the Plugins page of wp-admin – although they do appear in a special Must-Use section – and cannot be disabled except by removing the plugin file from the must-use directory, which is found in wp-content/mu-plugins by default.

So, the best practice is to use `add_filter` as you would normally do, but place those calls in a file on the `wp-content/mu-plugins` folder.

Comment: Could you put it in plugins -> includes -> admin -> admin.php say? Or do we need a script that is always being executed no matter what?

Comment: I'm just starting with wordpress and php so I'm a total newb, where would you advise placing the add_filter() calls, keeping in mind I have the default plugins only so far. I have no clue which ones are being used yet.

Comment: @Burkely91 I have expanded the answer, hope it's more clear now!

Comment: Thank you! :) Just to be triple sure, at the minute I have two files in there - endurance-page-cache.php and endurance-php-edge.php - do you know of any possible conflicts if I call add_filter at the end of either of those files?

Comment: I think you should ask a new question at [wordpress.se]